# 22P02: invalid input syntax for type smallint

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

This error a bit confusing for me since i don't have any property with type "smallint".

```
at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|211_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at gspark.Service.Implementation.GenericRepository`1.ListAsync(ISpecification`1 specification) in C:\Users\GSpark\source\repos\gspark\gspark.Service\Implementation\GenericRepository.cs:line 37
   at gspark.API.Controllers.TracksController.GetAllTracks(TrackSpecParams trackParams, Boolean isDraft) in C:\Users\GSpark\source\repos\gspark\gspark\Controllers\TracksController.cs:line 31
   at lambda_method202(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at gspark.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\GSpark\source\repos\gspark\gspark\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 24
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 22P02
    MessageText: invalid input syntax for type smallint: ""
    File: numutils.c
    Line: 247
    Routine: pg_strtoint16|url: http://localhost/api/Tracks|action: GetAllTracks|gspark.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync| body:
```

GetAllTracks:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyList<DtoReturnTrack>>> GetAllTracks([FromQuery] TrackSpecParams trackParams, bool isDraft)
    {
        var spec = new TrackWithUsersSpecification(trackParams);
        var tracks = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Track>().ListAsync(spec);
        var tracksDraft = tracks.Where(x => x.IsDraft == isDraft).ToList();
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IReadOnlyList<DtoReturnTrack>>(tracks));
    }
```

Track model:

```
public class TrackSpecParams
{
    public string? SortBy { get; set; }
    public int? GenreId { get; set; }
    public double minPrice { get; set; } = 0;
    public double maxPrice { get; set; } = 999.9;
    public int? KeyId { get; set; }
    public double minBpm { get; set; } = 0;
    public double maxBpm { get; set; } = 250;
    private string _search;

    public string? Search
    {
        get => _search; 
        set => _search = value.ToLower();
    }
```

In trackParams:

```
public TrackWithUsersSpecification(TrackSpecParams trackParams)
        : base(t =>
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trackParams.Search) || (t.Title.ToLower().Contains(trackParams.Search))) &&
            (!trackParams.GenreId.HasValue || t.GenreId == trackParams.GenreId) &&
            (t.Price > (decimal)trackParams.minPrice && t.Price < (decimal)trackParams.maxPrice) &&
            (!trackParams.KeyId.HasValue || t.TrackKey_Id == trackParams.KeyId) &&
            (Convert.ToInt16(t.Bpm) > (int)trackParams.minBpm && Convert.ToInt16(t.Bpm) < (int)trackParams.maxBpm)
        )
    {
        AddInclude(track => track.User);
        AddInclude(track => track.Genre);
        AddInclude(track => track.Subgenre);
        AddInclude(track => track.Key);
        AddInclude(track => track.Comments);
        AddOrderByDescending(track => track.ReleaseDate);
```

I tried to remove isDraft and everything related to this property, but nothing changes. And also tried to drop database, delete migrations. ListAsync() works fine in other controllers.

Comment: The error indicates failed string to integer conversion in database (SQL).  Most likely caused by `Convert.ToInt16(t.Bpm)` (`smallint` db type maps to `Int16`) parts of the query filter specification. Not sure why you need all these conversions, storing numbers as strings in database is terrible and leads to unexpected conversion errors. Anyway, concentrate on that part (turn on the EF Core log to see the failing SQL).

Comment: The PostgreSQL log file should contain the statement that caused the error. Please add that to the question.